# How to prevent certain files from being sourced

Tags: startup

I am not happy with the behavior of the `indent/html.vim` file, so I made a custom one in `~/.vim/indent/html.vim`. However, `vim -V2` still revealed to me that the `/usr/share/vim/vim80/indent/html.vim` is still sourced.

How do I prevent the latter from being sourced? I don't really want to remove that file manually and I am afraid I will than have to do that every time I update my system.

Comment: Did you include a `let b:did_indent = 1` in your custom indent script? The default indent scripts check for the existence of this variable and exit early if it is defined.

Comment: Another option is `exists("*HtmlIndent")`. That is looking for the function `HtmlIndent` to be defined. Not sure which script is run first, but if it's your custom indent than either of these options should work.